# Allow portrait Only - Works in iOS6 but not iOS5

Tags: ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate, interface-orientation

I'm building a project with a Base SDK of iOS 6.0.

In Targets > Summary I've set the Supported Device orientations' to portrait only (the other orientations are unselected).

This works great when I run the app in the 6.0 simulator, the app is locked to portrait as intended. However when I run the the 5.1 simulator, it's supporting both landscape orientations (but not upside down)!?

I want to force portrait throughout every view in the entire app (bar one view controller). Currently when testing in iOS 5.1 it allows rotation no matter what I do.

Despite being depreciated in iOS6, I've kept:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

but that doesn't do anything.

How can I force portrait only in iOS 5.0 also?

Comment: delete your app from simulator ,clean your project and delete derived data and then try run your app again

Comment: i tried for you.its working correctly..No problem

Comment: Thank R.A It was my bad, I had other code that was interfering with this which was causing the strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` should do the trick. Are you sure it is executing? Are you sure it is defined in your main view controller, not somewhere else?